# Dismiss actionSheet before action under it's button is completed

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet, dismiss

My problem is that i have an ActionSheet, which is disappearing from screen only when action under this button is completed. My problem is that i want to click 'save' inside my action sheet, then dismiss action sheet and then to show some alert, informing user to wait until saving is done. Currently it works different: firstly action sheet is shown, then there is saving message UNDER action sheet, finally action sheet is removed from view.. so user doesnt see any alert message.

How to dismiss actionSheet earlier than xcode does it?

Method under sheetActionButton:

```
- (IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender
{
UIAlertView *alert;
alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Saving photo to library\nPlease Wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];
[alert show];
UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
indicator.center = CGPointMake(alert.bounds.size.width / 2, alert.bounds.size.height - 50);
[indicator startAnimating];
[alert addSubview:indicator];
[indicator release];

[self saveImageToCameraRoll];

[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move your `saveImageToCameraRoll` method onto a separate thread, or at least asynchronously on the main thread. Then you can dismiss the alert and `saveAction:` can return before it completes.

The simplest way to do this would be using `dispatch_async`. Use `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)` to get a queue for a separate thread, or `dispatch_get_main_queue()` for the main thread. Make sure not to do any UI work (or use any APIs which aren't thread-safe) on other threads!

---

Edit: more detail:

```
- (IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert;
    alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Saving photo to library\nPlease Wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];
    [alert show];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    indicator.center = CGPointMake(alert.bounds.size.width / 2, alert.bounds.size.height - 50);
    [indicator startAnimating];
    [alert addSubview:indicator];
    [indicator release];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // Save in the background
        [self saveImageToCameraRoll];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Perform UI functions on the main thread!
            [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I've tried to modify this by your advice: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{[self saveImageToCameraRoll];}); ->now it is working completely different however still wrong: actionSheet is dismissed, but alert is showing after dispatch_async finish working o.O Why so..? I want do dismiss actionSheet, show alert, saving action, dismiss alert. Atm it's dismissing actionSheet, saving action, show alert, dismiss alert even tho in code i wrote it different.

Comment: changed it according to some tutorial: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self saveImageToCameraRoll];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), completion);
    }); where completion is a method parameter: completion:(void (^)(void))completion and i send a NULL to it when calling. The problem i've described in previous comment still exists.

Comment: Oh sorry. You need to move `[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];` inside the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ ... });` block.

Comment: Now its a never ending story ;) alert never is dismissed :/ I'm trying to modify code to fix it

Comment: Got it: had to delete: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), completion); and now works as a charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: have same code already :) Thanks for super fast and accurate help!